# Show that $u$ is an integral solution

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Show that $u(x, t) = g(x-bt) $  is an integral solution of:

$u_t (t, x) + bu_x(t, x) = 0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t>0$,

$u(0,x) = g(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R} $.

I was trying to do it just by the definition of an integral solution, but it didn't work... I was doing it just the way the picture shows. [image]

Comment: I think the issue here is in what is meant by an integral solution. Here are two PDE references from online: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/chap2.pdf, http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/first_integrals_partdiff_eq.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to establish a new variable $\xi = x - bt$. Then $u(x,t) = g(\xi(x,t)).$

Then $u_t = g_\xi\xi_t = -bg_\xi$.

Similarly, $u_x = g_\xi\xi_x = g_\xi$.

Substituting back into the original PDE produces $-bg_\xi + bg_\xi = 0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $g_\xi$? Shouldn't it be $u_t = g_t(\xi(x, t)) \cdot (-b) $?

Comment: It's an application of chain rule.

Comment: In other proofs, you may see something like -bg' instead to indicate the derivative of whatever function g enclosed x-bt. I prefer to define another variable. Consider if g(x-bt) = (x-bt)^2 to see exactly what I mean. You'd have to handle the square that encloses x-bt.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$u_t(x,t)=-bg'(x-bt)$$

and

$$u_x(x,t)=g'(x-bt).$$

It follows that

$$u_t (t, x) + bu_x(t, x) = 0$$

for $x \in \mathbb R$ and $t >0.$ Furthermor we have

$$u(x,0)=g(x).$$

Comment: But g doesnt have to be differentiable...

Answer (score 0):

$$u_t (t, x) + bu_x(t, x) = 0\tag1$$
which is of the form $~Pp + Qq  = R~$, where $~p=u_t (t, x)~$,$~q=u_x(t, x)~$,$~P=1~$,$~Q=b~$and$~R=0~.$
Lagrange subsidiary or auxiliary  equations $$\dfrac{dt}{P}=\dfrac{dx}{Q}=\dfrac{du}{R}$$
$$\implies\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{b}=\dfrac{du}{0}$$
Taking first two ratios, $~~~\dfrac{dt}{1}=\dfrac{dx}{b}~$

Integrating we have $~~~x=bt+c_1\implies c_1=x-bt~$,  where$~c_1~$is constant.

From the last two ratios, $~~~\dfrac{dx}{b}=\dfrac{du}{0}~$

Integrating we have $~~~u=c_2~$,  where$~c_2~$is constant.

Hence the required  general solution is  $~u(t,x)=f(x-bt)\tag2$where $~f~$ is arbitrary.

Given that $~u(0,x) = g(x)~$.

So from equation $(2)$, $~g(x)=f(x)~$.

Hence the solution  of the equation $(1)$ is $$u(x, t) = g(x-bt)$$